# Does anyone know of a g-code parser that translates user input to g-code?

Tags: parsing, generator, code-generation, converters, g-code

I am building a stretching stage to be distributed publicly for scientific testing of soft-bodied electronics and I am writing a GUI that allows users to input stretching distance (x) and number of cycles (times it will be stretched x distance. Does anyone know of a parser that would take the user inputs from my GUI and translate them to gcode? obviously I would have to find some way of bridging the programs but yeah.
I'm new to coding so sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: I believe "parsing" is the wrong word/tag. Possibly converting to or generating g-code would be better.

Comment: consider  gcode transpilers I have listed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/CNC/comments/b9xsal/many_dialects_of_gcode/).

Comment: What you are talking about is called [conversational programming](https://www.fanucamerica.com/products/cnc/cnc-technology/conversational-programming). There are SDKs available from FANUC that allow you to write software that runs on the control itself. It really depends upon what control you are writing for. G-Code is not generic. It must be tailored to a specific control and machine type.